# Scanf allows storing a bigger number of characters in an static array

Tags: c

In the code below, as you can see, the length of my array is `10`. When I use `scanf` to read some characters into the array, it allow me to surpass that number. Why is it possible?

I already tried with strings of smaller sizes and I see what I expected: an error about "stack smashing detected".

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char nome[10];
    printf("Nome:   ");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    printf("\n\n%s\n", nome);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: "it allow me to pass that number." -- what does this mean?  Could you show specific input examples?

Comment: It's possible because overflow protection in `scanf()` is not inherent. You need to code that protection yourself: `if (scanf("%9s", nome) != 1) /* error */;`

Answer (score 1):

A precondition for the `%s` format specifier of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is that the destination array *must* have enough space, as you point out.

However, the fact that it *may* work by chance when you slightly surpass that number does not mean it will *always* works. It is undefined behavior.

In particular, what is most likely happening here is that you are not triggering the stack smashing detector when you only overwrite a few extra characters.

Comment: Thanks alot everyone that answer and corrected my question! Aprecciated!